# I propose to elect by 3 quotas, each per one-thirds-contiguously of time-zones

Tags: discussion, election, feedback

In [the current EL&U moderator elections](https://english.stackexchange.com/election) most candidates, except one from UK, are from the USA what is somehow predetermines the situation that I shall be unmoderated for long periods of time since I am at GMT+6.

I am afraid that my posts would not be closed and deleted promptly enough.

Would not it be better if moderators be dispersed through time-zones?
I believe that quotas should be fixed per time-zones parts.

Comment: Now this question—I can understand why it was voted down, as it isn't really meant seriously. Even so, both this question and Reg's comment on Jeff's answer below were pretty funny to read.

Answer (score 7):

No, we don't support this. We look for great moderators wherever in the world they come from; enforcing time zone restrictions would be too limiting.

Most elections *in practice* produce at least US and europe, which is adequate coverage.

Comment: I believe Europe and US are in the same one-third.  2/3 is undercovered.

Comment: @vgv8: well, replying in the same cheerful tongue-in-cheek spirit you showed in the wording of your question: feel free to move to New Zealand and run for mod from there. You still have three days left. Alternatively, you can always vote to close or delete your posts yourself, from any time zone. Hope that helps! (^_^)

Comment: @RegDwight, I did not grasp what you wrote. I am already living in the same time-slot with New Zealand and I am not going to run from anwhere for mod.

Comment: I believe that Europe and America are not in the same timezone, and they are two different continents. Differently, I could not explain why an airplane takes more than 7 hours to go from Europe to America.

Answer (score 4):

In practice, there is very little moderator activity which needs split-second response time from moderators. We do not request nor expect moderators to keep constant vigil over the site at all times. For that reason, there is little *practical* value to spreading three moderators across the thirds of the globe.

Some moderators cannot moderate while working; some only use the site *while* working. Some are night owls, while others not. So everyone has their own "peak contribution" timezone, independent of where they live. There will be a statistical tendency for moderators to reside in the timezones where most of the activity comes from — more users, more likelihood moderators will be from there. Makes sense. So, I see no need to divvy up the moderators in this fashion.

I have nominated about 140 [pro tem moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and timezone coverage has never been an issue.